# Is there a way to compare 2 signals with different sampling rate in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, correlation

I want to compare 2 technically identical signals.
One was sampled by an osciloscope, with a sampling rate of 50KHz.
The other one, was sampled by my acquisition system with a sampling rate of 10KHz.
Both we're sampled at the same point and same time, and i want the correlation between the two.

Is there a way to do that in Python?

Comment: Please show 1. a copy pasteable snippet of the data, or mock data generation 2. your attempt. Please read [mre]

Comment: Without more information, the best I can offer is interpolation of the 50KHz to 10Khz using spline (or other) methods, then doing simple correlation. If this is not what you were looking for, do tell what you tried and why that isn't enough.